# Custom SQL Function Not Found on Server Node at Run-time

Tags: ignite

Custom SQL function works fine for me when it is used in a client Java app as described at https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/custom-sql-functions. However, when it is deployed to Ignite server nodes into its lib directory and invoked via standard SQL through JDBC, Ignite says

"SQL Error [42000] ... Function ... not found ...  [90022-195]".

Below is the Ignite configuration used at startup.

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="MyFunctions"/>
                        <property name="sqlFunctionClasses" value="MyFunctions"/>
                </bean>
        </list>
</property>
```

I also tried cache name "default"  but it has the same issue. If I use the cache name for the custom SQL function that is the same name as the table, Ignite says

"Cache configuration mismatch (local cache was created via Ignite API, while remote cache was created via CREATE TABLE):"

Ignite loaded the custom Java jar file for sure, because when it was not not deployed, Ignite would say it could not load the custom class.

The query is

SELECT *  FROM Country WHERE sqr(2) > 100;

What changes are needed for Ignite server nodes to use custom SQL functions in SQL statements that are issued through JDBC ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `sqlFunctionClasses` should be fully qualified, as in `com.your.package.MyFunctions`.

You should also be adding it to Country cache and not MyFunctions. If Country is indeed created with `CREATE TABLE`, you could try and define it in [cache template](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table#section-parameters). E.g. you could use `WITH "TEMPLATE=MyFunctions"`.

Comment: For sqlFunctionClasses, given test purposes, this custom Java class does not have a package, so that was not included. 




For the cache name, I had already tried adding the custom Java class to Country cache but Ignite says "[SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine). class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cache configuration mismatch (local cache was created via Ignite API, while remote cache was created via CREATE TABLE: Country"

Comment: @Michael you should only start your cache once. CREATE TABLE is once. cacheConfiguration is the second time. You can use CREATE TABLE with template; or you can ditch CREATE TABLE and just use cacheConfiguration.